# CSS Help to see stars

Tags: css

I have looked around and have been unable to write a CSS code that is based on a 5 star rating system that will change based upon customer feedback. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: This sounds it would be much easier with Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a positioned sprite-sheet:

HTML:

```
<div class="rating one-star"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.rating
{
  background-image: url(stars.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

/* assume a star is 20x20 */

.one-star
{
  background-position: -80px 0;
}
.two-star
{
  background-position: -60px 0;
}
.three-star
{
  background-position: -40px 0;
}
.four-star
{
  background-position: -20px 0;
}
.five-star
{
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

Of course you may want the div to contain 5 links with star outlines, hover effects, or other such things.  It really depends on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As peterthegreat mentioned, you might want to look into a javascript solution.

[Example of a jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SimpleStarRater)